# Lead paint test showing colour not listed

Tags: paint, lead

I'm working on a basement reno in a 1950's house. As a precaution I bought a lead test kit to inspect whether or not the paint on my staircase contains lead. I used "Lead Inspector" by a brand called Abotex. I believe it's a sulfide lead test kit, it works by using a q-tip to apply a very smelly chemical to the scored paint and the colour of the reaction should indicate if lead is present. According to this company it should be anything in the range of yellow, brown and black.

The paint on the stringers tested fine (it's some kind of all purpose grey concrete paint) but the paint on the treads and risers, which is this hideous dusty rose, turned a blue-gray color immediately, but the q-tip stayed white and clear.

To those experienced, does this sound like an unrelated chemical reaction? Or should I consider any colour change a positive result? The kit was good, not damaged or opened. I can't buy another brand because this is the only test kit available in stores for some reason.

I have written to the company and I'm hoping I'll get a response but their site is a sketchy older WordPress site so I'm not holding onto much hope there...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't get an email response in a reasonable amount of time, you might consider calling them or looking to see if they have a chat facility. Also, does "only one available in stores" include on-line stores? You might have to broaden your shopping experience. You might also consider buying a second test kit to see if you get the same response - it's possible that your was chemically damaged _before_ being packaged. I have no idea how much lead test kits cost, so I don't know what impact that may have...